# Script using multiprocessing module does not terminate

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

The following code, does not print `"here"`. What is the problem?
I tested it on both my machines (windows 7, Ubuntu 12.10), and
http://www.compileonline.com/execute_python_online.php
It does not print `"here"` in all cases.

```
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process


def runLang(que):
    print "start"
    myDict=dict()
    for i in xrange(10000):
        myDict[i]=i
    que.put(myDict)
    print "finish"


def run(fileToAnalyze):
    que=Queue()
    processList=[]
    dicList=[]
    langs= ["chi","eng"]
    for lang in langs:
        p=Process(target=runLang,args=(que,))
        processList.append(p)
        p.start()

    for p1 in processList:
        p1.join()

    print "here"

    for _ in xrange(len(langs)):
        item=que.get()
        print item
        dicList.append(item)

if __name__=="__main__":
    processList = []
    for fileToAnalyse in ["abc.txt","def.txt"]:
        p=Process(target=run,args=(fileToAnalyse,))
        processList.append(p)
        p.start()
    for p1 in processList:
        p1.join()
```

Answer (score 17):

This is because when you `put` lots of items into a `multiprocessing.Queue`, they eventually get buffered in memory, once the underlying `Pipe` is full. The buffer won't get flushed until something starts reading from the other end of the `Queue`, which will allow the `Pipe` to accept more data. A `Process` cannot terminate until the buffer for all its `Queue` instances have been entirely flushed to their underlying `Pipe`. The implication of this is that if you try to `join` a process without having another process/thread calling `get` on its `Queue`, you could deadlock. This is [mentioned in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues):

> **Warning**
>
> As mentioned above, if a child process has put items on a queue (and
>   it has not used `JoinableQueue.cancel_join_thread`), then that process
>   will not terminate until all buffered items have been flushed to the
>   pipe.
>
> This means that if you try joining that process you may get a deadlock
>   unless you are sure that all items which have been put on the queue
>   have been consumed. Similarly, if the child process is non-daemonic
>   then the parent process may hang on exit when it tries to join all its
>   non-daemonic children.
>
> Note that a queue created using a manager does not have this issue.

You can fix the issue by not calling `join` until after you empty the `Queue` in the parent:

```
for _ in xrange(len(langs)):
    item = que.get()
    print(item)
    dicList.append(item)

# join after emptying the queue.
for p in processList:
    p.join()

print("here")
```