# Multiprocessing.Process never joins

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing

I have subclassed the multiprocessing.Process class for severall worker classes that communicate via Queues. Each process has a imput queue and/or a output_queue.

They work fine and do what they should (as far as I have debugged my program), but if I try to join the subprocesses, some of of them won't join. I configured a logger to print all (sub)debug messages. The last thing both processes show is a `[DEBUG/PROCESSNAME] joining queue thread`. This makes sense, because the non-joining processes share a queue, so that might be why they are affected.

Any ideas why the queues won't join?

Comment: You haven't included enough information to say for sure, but my guess is its this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26738648/script-using-multiprocessing-module-does-not-terminate/26738946#26738946

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly my problem. Why didn't I find that? As you wrote a comment instead of an answer, I can not "accept" it to mark this question as solved.