# What can cause a seemingly infinite loop in my parallelized code?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Here is what my code looks like:

```
def data_processing_function(some_data):
    do some things with some_data
    queue.put(some_data)

processes = []
queue = Queue()

for data in bigdata:
    if data meets certain criteria:
        prepared_data = prepare_data(data)
        processes += [Process(target=data_processing_function,
                              args=prepared_data)]
        processes[-1].start()

for process in processes:
    process.join()

results = []
for i in range(queue.qsize()):
    result += [queue.get()]
```

When I tried this with a reduced dataset, everything went smoothly. But when I launched it with the full dataset, it looks like the script entered an infinite loop during the `process.join()` part.
In a desperate moved, I killed all the processes except the main one, and the execution went on. Now it hangs on the `queue.get()` without notable CPU or RAM activity.

What can cause this? Is my code properly designed?

Comment: Maybe the code you didn't show is the answer.

Comment: Does this mean this part is OK? I'm trying again right now with 1 queue by process, I hope this will help...

Comment: I didn't try, but at first look, it seems ok to me

Comment: It definitely looks like it's getting stuck (or maybe just taking a long time) inside `do some things with some_data`. Add some logging or print statements to make sure it's moving. Also what you're doing is very standard and can be reduced to a call to [`multiprocessing.Pool.map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html).

Comment: My problem was previously discussed here I think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26738648/script-using-multiprocessing-module-does-not-terminate . Unfortunately I don't understand the answer. If I empty the queue before joining, won't I miss some results from the latest processes I launched?

Comment: See the subsection titled **Joining processes that use queues** in the  multiprocessing [Programming guidelines](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines) documentation. There, the example which will deadlock looks a lot like what you're doing. I think that is what the answer to other question is talking about.